# How I can use pagination for my Class (DetailView) with get_context_data?

Tags: django, view, detailview

How can I get pagination for the current code? I can't change the DetailView to View or ListView, so in this class I get a filter of products.

```
class CategoryDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Category
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    context_object_name = 'category'
    template_name = 'category_products.html'
    ...


def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    ...
    products = Product.objects.filter(id__in=[pf_['product_id'] for pf_ in pf])
    context['category_products'] = products
    return context
```

Comment: I think the simplest would be to turn it into a `ListView` with `Product` as model. The `Category` can still be send to the context, so I'm not sure why it cannot be changed to a `ListView`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, I'm use get_object() in this function. 
"category = self.get_object()" and "if not query and not self.request.GET: context['category_products'] = category.product_set.all()"

Comment: Can you share the `path` that points to the `CategoryDetailView` together with the `Product` and `Category` model?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, The site does not allow to lay out completely, so I put the code in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Wihomie/htfrsz18/2/

Comment: can you also share the relevant part of the `urls.py` as well as the `Product` and `Category` model?

Comment: yes, of course https://jsfiddle.net/Wihomie/7h1m4L8q/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically one picks the class-based view that is the most convenient to do the job. You can see your view as a `ListView` of `Product`s that are related to a certain category. By doing this, you make it more convenient to retrieve the related `Product`s, and less convenient to obtain the relevant `Category`, but the last one is easier.

We can implement the view as:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

class CategoryDetailView(ListView):
    model = Product
    context_object_name = 'category_products'
    template_name = 'category_products.html'
    paginate_by = 1
    # …

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset().filter(
            category__slug=self.kwargs['slug']
        )
        qd = self.request.GET.copy()
        qd.pop(self.page_kwarg, None)
        if 'search' in self.request.GET:
            qs = qs.filter(title__icontains=self.request.GET['search'])
        elif qd:
            qs = qs.filter(
                features__value__in=[v for _, vs in qd.lists() for v in vs]
        )
        if 'sort' in self.request.GET:
            qs = qs.order_by(self.request.GET['sort'])
        return qs

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['category'] = get_object_or_404(Category, pk=self.kwargs['pk'], slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        return context
```

The `get_queryset` here thus implements the advanced querying you implemented, and we add the `category` by overriding the `get_queryset`. This queryset will then automatically get paginated by the logic of the `ListView`.

I would however advise to simplify the logic, usually advanced filtering only makes it more error prone. Furthermore ordering by an arbitrary parameter introduces a security vulnerability, one could for example try to filter on `some_foreignkey__some_secure_field` to expose data. You thus might want to validate that the `order` is in a list of acceptable values.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But now I'm facing a problem. I use pagination, as written in the official documentation paginate_by = 1, and use page_obj in the template. The page displays the correct number of pages based on the number of products. But when going to the page, it gives an error that "That page contains no results".

Comment: @ВалентинИващенко: that is likely because you "drop" the rest of the querystring (the other parameters in `request.GET`). You should pass the rest of the query string parameters again when going to a prev/next/other page https://stackoverflow.com/a/70025071/67579

Comment: works, but only when I apply one of the filters. Doesn't work without filters. Everything is correct in the url field "/subcategories?page=2&" and with filters "/subcategories?page=2&queryset=value".

Comment: @ВалентинИващенко: yes, because your logic will use the `page=...` as value as well in since then `if request.GET` is true, you should filter it out. See edit.

Comment: don't helped for me.

Comment: @ВалентинИващенко: yes, I found a small problem. Updated